# Access sub environment variable in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have the following environment variable:

```
$ printenv
...
    VCAP_SERVICES={"mariadbent":[{
  "label": "mariadbent",
  "provider": null,
  "plan": "usage",
  "name": "stackoverflow-database",
  "tags": [
    "mariadb",
    "mysql"
  ],
  "instance_name": "stackoverflow-database",
  "binding_name": null,
  "credentials": {
    "host": "some-url-to-the-database.service",
    "hostname": "some-url-to-the-database.service",
    "port": 7689,
    "name": "JDFJHDJF_DFJKDHFUD_DFUZDKFJDKJF",
    "database": "JDFJHDJF_DFJKDHFUD_DFUZDKFJDKJF",
    "username": "hsdfhsjkfhsjkhfjk",
    "password": "iuzwerhsdjkfjkasd",
    "database_uri": "mysql://dfdfdfdfdf:jrb4j4QxzgbAcfLk@some-url-to-the-database.service:3306/JDFJHDJF_DFJKDHFUD_DFUZDKFJDKJF?reconnect=true",
    "uri": "mysql://dfdfdfdfdf:jrb4j4QxzgbAcfLk@some-url-to-the-database.service:3306/JDFJHDJF_DFJKDHFUD_DFUZDKFJDKJF?reconnect=true",
    "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://some-url-to-the-database.service:3306/JDFJHDJF_DFJKDHFUD_DFUZDKFJDKJF?user=dfdfdfdfdf&password=jrb4j4QxzgbAcfLk"
  },
  "syslog_drain_url": null,
  "volume_mounts": [

  ]
}]}
```

I can get the whole "pack" of data with `System.out.println("VCAP_SERVICES: " + System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"));`, but I would like to extract some field in the above output, like the `username`.

How could I do that?

Comment: `VCAP_SERVICE` looks like a json. You can use Jackson or any json parser and get the value you want.

Comment: Looks like JSON, so you need to parse it using some JSON library, e.g. Jackson.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "sub environment variable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VCAP_SERVICE` hold an json. You can use an json parser to get a value from it.

Here is an example using `Jackson`, but there a more libs which can do this.

```
try{

    String json = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"); //NullPointerException, SecurityException

    JsonNode jsonNode = (new ObjectMapper()).readTree(json); //IOException

    if(jsonNode.has("mariadbent") && jsonNode.get("mariadbent").isArray()){

        for(JsonNode elem : jsonNode.get("mariadbent")){

            if(elem.has("credentials")){

                JsonNode cred = elem.get("credentials");

                if(cred.has("host")){

                    System.out.println(
                        cred.get("host").asText() //some-url-to-the-database.service
                    );

                }else{ System.out.println("no host"); }

            }else{ System.out.println("no credentials"); }

        }

    }else{ System.out.println("no mariadbent or not array"); }

}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

For this you need lib `Jackson Databind`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9.3